# Derivation of Solution to Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, heat-equation

I am looking at a derivation of the solution to the Heat Equation for my partial differential equations course, but I am stuck on one part of the derivation and I want to understand everything that is happening.  Below is an excerpt from the notes:

---

Recalling that $Q(x, t) = g(p)$, where $p = \frac{x}{\sqrt{4kt}}$, we
obtain the following explicit formula for $Q$
$$Q(x,t) = c_1\int_0^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{4kt}}} e^{-p^2}dp + c_2 $$

---

Now, my question is **why we have chosen the bounds of integration to be $(0,\frac{x}{\sqrt{4kt}})$**.  This seems rather arbitrary.  Could we have chosen something else as the bounds?  This method seems to be standard in all sources I have checked so I believe there must be a concrete reason.  I am super stuck on this so any help would be greatly appreciated.  **Here is a screenshot of the notes if anyone needs more reference**.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the title of the book @glawley I can't read pics ..

Comment: The explanation is mostly right there in the text you clipped. Step 1 starts with an argument that $$Q(x,t) = q\left(\frac x{\sqrt t}\right)$$ for some function $q$. They then define $g(z) = q(\sqrt{4k}z)$ "for notational convenience". I.e., you are reading a cleaned-up version of the derivation where they've already found out what value works and are simply introducing it now. This value was chosen so that equation (5), $g'' + 2pg = 0$, would not involve $k$. It would still be solvable without the change, but a little messier to write.